# Why struts2 add an &nbsp; escape for white spaces in the string

Tags: java, html, json, struts2

I have some code like this in struts2 interceptor:

```
 final ReplaceStrategy highLightStrategy = new ReplaceStrategy() {
    @Override
    public String replaceWith(String keyword) {
        return "<span class='highLight'>" + keyword + "</span>";
    }
 };
```

It means that return `"<span class='highLight'>" + keyword + "</span>"` for some keyword.

my **strutsconfig.xml** is like this:

```
    <action name="searchJoySpu" class="com.web.action.SpuSearchAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">resp</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

When I get the result,the result of the span tag have some **`&nbsp;`** escape in the return string. like this:

```
范德萨<span&nbsp;class='highLight'>哈哈</span>哈
```

Between the span and class, there is a **`&nbsp;`** which result the html tag parse failure for fe.

How can I return the truly string with no **`&nbsp;`** escape. And I don't want to use struts2 **`<s:property>`** tag.

The return json is:

```
{
 "pageIndex": 0,
 "pageSize": 20,
 "recordCount": 4,
 "records": [
 {
  "auditContent": "",
  "auditID": 2464,
  "auditStatus": 1,
  "brandID": 251,
  "brandName": "<span&nbsp;class='highLight'>测试</span>",
  "specialItemList": [
    {
      "content": "<p><span&nbsp;class='highLight'>测试</span>     <span&nbsp;class='highLight'>测试</span></p>",
      "title": "<span&nbsp;class='highLight'>测试</span>"
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use struts2 tag? It helps much by encoding strings before you write them to JSP to prevent XSS.

Comment: How do you *get* the result?

Comment: @AleksandrM  use json plugin,and strutsconfig.xml  as described above.

Comment: @RomanC It's you again.^_^  I don't use  struts2 tag cause the freemark has already done.

Comment: @AleksandrM  the return json was add into the question.The way I show the json,I use AngularJs tag:ng-hmtl.

Comment: You need to debug to see where `&nbsp;` is coming from. AFAIK json result won't add it. Since you're doing that in interceptor then maybe some interceptor. Debug it.

Comment: The freemark obsolete here what is your controller?